# Wondering if the sql statement is correct

Tags: mysql, sql

The attached image is what I have in my DB table. I wished to count the number of "IsRead" that are true for a unique productSerial. The productSerial here is not a primary key, hence it can be repeated. But I was unsure how to write the sql statement for this..

For example the result should be displayed like :

```
10 - 3
11 - 2
12 - 1
```

I came out with this but I wondered whether it was correct, and hope u all can correct me if i am wrong.

```
Select DISTINCT productSerial
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(IsRead) where IsRead = 'True' FROM testing);
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select ProductSerial, count(*)
from testing
where IsRead = 'True'
group by ProductSerial
order by ProductSerial
```

Comment: For the first time I see some who doesn't have much rep YET nailed it with 5 votes, +1 for that. @VinnyRoe =)

Comment: Thanks @bonCodigo. Not much rep, but I have 20+ years at this, and it wasn't exactly a hard question!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ProductSerial, Count(1)
FROM testing
WHERE IsRead = 'True'
GROUP BY ProductSerial
ORDER BY ProductSerial ASC
```

Should give the same results, and is a much simpler query

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not correct. You can also greatly simplify the *WHERE* clause like so:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT productSerial, COUNT(IsRead) FROM testing 
WHERE IsRead = 'True' GROUP BY productSerial
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
Select productSerial , COUNT(IsRead) FROM testing where IsRead= 'True' group by productSerial
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select
    ProductSerial,
    Count(IsRead) as Count
from
    testing
where
    IsRead = 'True'
group by
    ProductSerial
order by
    ProductSerial ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Do Easily As Like Following

```
SELECT `ProductSerial` , COUNT( `IsRead` ) AS NumberOfProduct
FROM `table_name`
WHERE `IsRead` = 'True'
GROUP BY `ProductSerial`
```